# RabbitMQ - Java Spring - how to init exchange to several queues?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq

I'm having difficulty finding a Spring way to initial an exchange that's sending the incoming message to more then 1 queue - on my Spring-boot application:

I can't find a good way to define a seconds exchange-queue binding.

I'm using RabbitTemplate as the producer client.

The RabbitMQ 6 page tutorial doesn't really help with that since:

1. the only initial several temporary queues from the Consumer on-demand (while I need to the Producer to do the binding - to persistant queues)
2. The examples are for basic java usage - not using Spring capabilities.

I also failed to find how to implement it via The spring AMQP pages.

what I got so far, is trying to inject the basic java binding to the spring way of doing it - but it's not working....

```
@Bean
public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() throws IOException {
    CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory("localhost");
    connectionFactory.setUsername("guest");
    connectionFactory.setPassword("guest");

    Connection conn = connectionFactory.createConnection();
    Channel channel = conn.createChannel(false);

    channel.exchangeDeclare(SPRING_BOOT_EXCHANGE, "fanout");
    channel.queueBind(queueName, SPRING_BOOT_EXCHANGE, ""); //first bind
    channel.queueBind(queueName2, SPRING_BOOT_EXCHANGE, "");// second bind

    return connectionFactory;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated

### Edited

I *think* the problem arise with the fact that every time I restart my server it tries to redefine the exchange-query-binding - while they persist in the broker...
I managed to define them manually via the brokers UI console - so the Producer only aware of the exchange name, and the Consumer only aware to it's relevant queue.
Is there a way to define those element progrematically - but in such a way so it won't be redefined\overwritten if already exist from previous restarts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use an approach similar to the following to send data from one specific input channel to several input queues of other consumers:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow integrationFlow(final RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate, final AmqpHeaderMapper amqpHeaderMapper) {
    IntegrationFlows
        .from("some-input-channel")
        .handle(Amqp.outboundAdapter(rabbitTemplate)
        .headerMapper(headerMapper))
        .get()    
}

@Bean
public AmqpHeaderMapper amqpHeaderMapper() {
    final DefaultAmqpHeaderMapper headerMapper = new DefaultAmqpHeaderMapper();
    headerMapper.setRequestHeaderNames("*");
    return headerMapper;
}

@Bean
public ConnectionFactory rabbitConnectionFactory() {
   return new CachingConnectionFactory();
}

@Bean
public RabbitAdmin rabbitAdmin(final ConnectionFactory rabbitConnectionFactory) {
    final RabbitAdmin rabbitAdmin = new RabbitAdmin(rabbitConnectionFactory);
    rabbitAdmin.afterPropertiesSet();
    return rabbitAdmin;
}

@Bean
public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate(final ConnectionFactory rabbitConnectionFactory, final RabbitAdmin rabbitAdmin) {
    final RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate();
    rabbitTemplate.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);

    final FanoutExchange fanoutExchange = new FanoutExchange(MY_FANOUT.getFanoutName());
    fanoutExchange.setAdminsThatShouldDeclare(rabbitAdmin);
    for (final String queueName : MY_FANOUT.getQueueNames) {
        final Queue queue = new Queue(queueName, true);
        queue.setAdminsThatShouldDeclare(rabbitAdmin);

        final Binding binding = BindingBuilder.bind(queue).to(fanoutExchange);
        binding.setAdminsThatShouldDeclare(rabbitAdmin);
    }
    rabbitTemplate.setExchange(fanoutExchange);    
}
```

and for completeness here's the enum for the fanout declaration:

```
public enum MyFanout {
    MY_FANOUT(Lists.newArrayList("queue1", "queue2"), "my-fanout"),

    private final List<String> queueNames;
    private final String fanoutName;

    MyFanout(final List<String> queueNames, final String fanoutName) {
        this.queueNames = requireNonNull(queueNames, "queue must not be null!");
        this.fanoutName = requireNonNull(fanoutName, "exchange must not be null!");
    }

    public List<String> getQueueNames() {
        return this.queueNames;
    }

    public String getFanoutName() {
        return this.fanoutName;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks!
That was the answer I was looking for.
also - for the sake of completeness - I found a way to it 'the java way' inside Spring Bean:

```
  @Bean
public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() throws IOException {
    CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory("localhost");
    connectionFactory.setUsername("guest");
    connectionFactory.setPassword("guest");

    Connection conn = connectionFactory.createConnection();
    Channel channel = conn.createChannel(false);

    // declare exchnage
    AMQP.Exchange.DeclareOk resEx = channel.exchangeDeclare(AmqpTemp.SPRING_BOOT_EXCHANGE_test, ExchangeTypes.FANOUT, true, false, false, null);

    // declares queues
    AMQP.Queue.DeclareOk resQ = channel.queueDeclare(AmqpTemp.Q2, true, false, false, null);
    resQ = channel.queueDeclare(AmqpTemp.Q3, true, false, false, null);

    // declare binding
    AMQP.Queue.BindOk resB = channel.queueBind(AmqpTemp.Q2, AmqpTemp.SPRING_BOOT_EXCHANGE_test, "");
    resB = channel.queueBind(AmqpTemp.Q3, AmqpTemp.SPRING_BOOT_EXCHANGE_test, "");
    // channel.queueBind(queueName2, SPRING_BOOT_EXCHANGE, "");

    return connectionFactory;
}
```

The problems I was having before, were do to the fact that I created some queues in my initial play with the code - and when I tried to reuse the same queue names it caused exception since they were initially defined differently - so - lesson learnt: rename the queues from the names you used when you 'played' with the code.